# Is it possible to change the filename convention in the Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

My team decided that we wanted to be consistent with our filename naming conventions and decided that we want to stick with underscores across all of our projects; this is not just Ember/frontend projects, but APIs, DBs, pattern library, style guides, etc. We also want to use the Ember CLI for or next frontend project. Is there an option to change the "dasherized" naming convention to be "underscored?" If not, how would we go about solving this? I'm hoping the solution would be easier than just making our own fork of the CLI.

Comment: nope, ember-cli is opinionated, you'll have to fork if you want that granular of control.

Comment: I have to agree with @Kingpin2k, there is no option so you have to modify the ember-cli source code and change the blueprints, resolver, etc. I don't think it's worth the trouble to change a greed upon convention set by the ember community.

Comment: There is no specific use changing file name convention...Its actually awesome that you don't need to create hooks etc to manage that...

Comment: you don't need to fork, you just need a custom resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Based on runspired's suggestion, here's a custom resolver that converts modules with _ to -:

```
import Resolver from 'ember-resolver';
import ModuleRegistry from 'ember-resolver/utils/module-registry';

function DasherizedModuleRegistry(entries) {
  var keys, key;

  this._entries = entries || requirejs.entries;

  // Convert underscore in module names to dashes
  keys = Object.keys(this._entries);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    var dasherizedKey = key.replace(/_/g, '-');
    if (dasherizedKey !== key) {
      this._entries[dasherizedKey] = this._entries[key];
      delete this._entries[key];
    }
  });
}

DasherizedModuleRegistry.prototype = Object.create(ModuleRegistry.prototype);
DasherizedModuleRegistry.prototype.constructor = DasherizedModuleRegistry;

export default Resolver.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    if (!this._moduleRegistry || !(this._moduleRegistry instanceof DasherizedModuleRegistry)) {
      this._moduleRegistry = new DasherizedModuleRegistry();
    }
  },
});
```

Place this into `app/resolver.js` in your ember-cli app. We have a mix of `components/foo_bar.js` and `components/bar-foo.js` and this resolver works for us.

Note that this conversion will be run in the client's browser on application boot and *might* slow it down with a large codebase.